# The average weight of $46$ weightlifters is $106$ kg; how many can weigh $125$ kg if none may drop below $82$ kg?

Tags: statistics, average

The average weight of $46$ weightlifters is $106$ kg. If none of the lifters weighs less than $82$ kg, at most how many of them can weigh more than $125$ kg?

We are given that $$\overline{X}=\dfrac{x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_{46}}{46}=106.$$ From here we can conclude $$x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_{46}=106\times46=4876 \text{ kg }$$ So the total weight of the weightlifters is $4876$ kg. We also know that $x_n\ge82$ kg for every $n$. I don't know what to do next. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No! None of the lifters weighs less than $82$ $kg$, right?

Comment: Look at "worst cases".  Suppose $N$ of them weigh exactly $82$.  In that case, how many could weigh $125+\epsilon$?

Comment: Why the downvote? I expect it's again too high expectations from the community.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
$
We can pair them off, one at a time. Say $x_1 = 82$ (the minimum weight), and then $x_2 = 125 + \varepsilon$, where $\ve$ is some small but positive number. The pair in total weigh $207 + \ve$, and there are $23$ such pairs. Thus, we have a total weight, at this point, of $4761 + 23 \ve$, but we also know to this to be equal to $4876$. Thus,

$$4761 + 23 \ve = 4876 \implies \ve = 5$$

So among them, there are $5$ kg extra per pair, and $23 \times 5 = 115$ in total spare. We can redistribute this to some pairs, with the lower-weight person receiving the weight. They each need $43 + \mu$  for some small positive $\mu$, and thus we can only give two people enough ($115/43 \approx 2.67$).

Thus, in total, $25$ people may exceed $125$ kg in weight (and $21$ do not).

To see that $26$ is not viable, suppose the remaining $20$ are at minimum weight. Then $26 \times 125 + 20 \times 82 = 4890$, just in excess of $4876$, with an average of $106.3 \ne 106$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't understand the idea behind this "some small but positive number". Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Basically we need to ensure that the weight is greater than $125$, but not equal to it. Maybe we can use $125.1$ or $125.01$ or $125.000000001$ or something, but we don't know exactly what the limit is; it's easier to just add "add on a small number and call it $\varepsilon$" though.

Comment: $
\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
$Thank you! I am not really sure I get the idea, though. Why do we need to pair the weightlifters off and why do we assume that the first in the pair has a weight of $82$ $kg$ and the second one has a weight of $125+\ve?$

Comment: The idea is to try to min-max the weights - someone as low as possible but within the limits, and someone just above the upper limit. This gives us a rough estimate for how many people we can have exceed the limit. We then see how much spare weight (the $\varepsilon$) this gives us to work with, in the hopes we can make even more people go above the limit. Think of it as starting with a rough guess, and then we try to refine that guess.

Comment: maximal number of greater than or equal to 125kg with a minimum of 82kg indicates only one of the low value and all the rest at or necessarily some amount above the mean.

Answer (score 2):

Let divide the $n=46$ lifters into $h$ "heavy" lifters (weight more than 125) and $t=n-h$ "thin" lifters. Then the respective averages (denoted by $X$, $X_h$, $X_t$) are related by

$$ 106 = X = \frac{h}{n} X_h + \frac{t}{n} X_t =\frac{h}{n}(X_h - X_t) + X_t $$

Obviously $$ X_h > 125, $$
$$ 82 \le X_t \le 106 $$

and

$$ \frac{h}{n} = \frac{106 - X_t}{X_h - X_t} <  \frac{106 - X_t}{125 - X_t} $$

The above is  decreasing in $X_t \in [82,106]$, hence its maximum occurs at $X_t= 82$, so

$$ \frac{h}{46} < \frac{106-82}{125-46} \implies h < 25.674$$

and the maximum number of heavy lifters is $25$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you explain to me this line $$ 106 = x = \frac{h}{n} x_h + \frac{t}{n} x_t =\frac{h}{n}(x_h - x_t) + x_t ?$$ What is $x,x_h$ and $x_t$?

Comment: $x =\overline{X}$ (average). $x_h$ is the average weight of the heavy lifters

Comment: But why $x=\dfrac{h}{n}x_h+\dfrac{t}{n}x_t$? And then how is this equal to $\dfrac{h}{n}\left(x_h-x_t\right)+x_t$?

Comment: The global average is the weighted average of the group averages. That's an standard and easy to prove result. Just write the sums. Or see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Basic_example

Comment: I got it. But why is this equal to $\dfrac{h}{n}(x_h-x_t)+x_t$?

Comment: Just replace $t=n-h$ and regroup terms.

Comment: I see it now. Why $x_h\ge125?$ If every "heavy" lifter weighs more than $125$, isn't $x_h>125$? Also how do you conclude $82\le x_t\le106$?

Comment: Corrected the first inequality. $X_t \ge 82$ because all lifters weight  at least 82

Comment: And why $x_t\le106?$